# how to retrieve particular value from json format into pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a json file from which i want to retrieve on particular values into dataframe columns like

```
    {'Benot':'50455','Madri':'18017','Madrar':'Ossur','Application':'Soft Top Post-op Shoe','Color':'Black','FasteningType':'Contact Closure','Material':'Cotton / Polyester','ShoeSize':'Male 9 to 11','Size':'Large','Style':'Open Toe / Closed Heel','Code':'42241709','User':'Male'}    
    {'Benot':'501455','Madri':'180117','Madrar':'Osur','Application':'SoftShoe','Color':'Black','Material':'Cotton / Polyester','ShoeSize':'Male 9 to 11','Size':'Large','Code':'42241709','User':'Male'}
```

The problem is the same data is not present inside every {} like in 'ShoeSize':'Male 9 to 11' is preset in one line but not in other line and for many other field

I just want to read 'Benot' , 'Madri' ,'Madrar' , 'Application', 'Code' is there any possible way to read  only this in dataframe
when i read file it throws error

```
         data = pd.read_csv('McKessonFullData.txt')
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

Is it possible to read particular values save it dataframe

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) with `lines=True`:

```
data = pd.read_json('McKessonFullData.txt', lines=True)
```

Comment: throws error  ValueError: Expected object or value                                 as i want to read only particular value from the field so i think reading as a text file and then reading particular value from it

Comment: @ParthTiwari - Are data confidental? If not, i spossible share file? Because if some encoding problem the best is working with original data

Comment: no its not confidential where should i share the file

Comment: @ParthTiwari - Super, then use gdocs, dropbox, wetransfer or similar

Comment: somehow i am not able to attach the file